# Script Lab for Outlook: Object doesn't support property or method 'addHandlerAsync' on default sample 'Create a new appointment'

Tags: office-js, scriptlab

I installed the Script Lab Add-In for Outlook but am getting the following error in the console:

"Object doesn't support property or method 'addHandlerAsync'",
"https://script-lab-runner.azureedge.net/",
94,
1,
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'addHandlerAsync'
]

I have simply selected the 'Create a new appointment' sample, but same problem happens on other samples. I have also verified that my IT department does not block access to the office.js on the appsforoffice link. [See Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pax0e.png)

I am using Outlook 2016 (16.0.5056.1000) MSO (16.0.4266.1001) 32-bit
Windows 10. This is part of the Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 Suite.

**If anybody has encountered this same problem, I would like to understand how to fix it and what might be preventing this from executing properly?**

The libraries tab has the defaults:

https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js

@types/office-js

office-ui-fabric-js@1.4.0/dist/css/fabric.min.css

office-ui-fabric-js@1.4.0/dist/css/fabric.components.min.css

core-js@2.4.1/client/core.min.js

@types/core-js

jquery@3.1.1

@types/jquery@3.3.1

Comment: Can you provide additional debugging information? What Version of Outlook are you on? (OWA, Win32?, Mac?). What is the Build version of Outlook? (i.e. it should look something like 16.0.XXXX.YYYY)

Comment: I've added details about my version of Office. I am using Outlook 2016 (16.0.5056.1000) MSO (16.0.4266.1001) 32-bit
Windows 10. This is part of the Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 Suite. The problem is that I have used this on another system with the same version of Outlook without an issue, so I am more curious about any potential backend pieces of Script Lab that might be blocked due to an AD policy, etc. I am unable to determine why the loader (??) is not working? Any info as to why the scripts might be blocked from being loaded might give me a clue?

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. `Office.context.mailbox.item.addHandlerAsync` is not supported in Outlook 2016 MSI, which is what you have installed. We have placed this issue in our backlog as office # 4692769. Regarding the fix, we unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point.